# input field doesnt allow to edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Hi guys I am trying to edit the input field below and cant.
I getting some data from a server and I am putting this data on the `value` of the input. The idea is that one we click the icon to allow the field to be editable but still cant edit.

This is the `input` with props customised:

```js
 <input
          {...field}
          //   required={props.required}
          disabled={props.disabled}
          value={props.value}
          type={props.type}
          autoComplete={props.autoComplete}
          pattern={props.pattern}
          className={`mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm  rounded-md ${
            error ? 'border-red-500' : 'border-gray-500'
          }
          ${
            props.disabled
              ? 'disabled:shadow-none disabled:bg-slate-50 disabled:text-slate-500 disabled:border-slate-200'
              : 'border-gray-500'
          } `}
        />
```

And here is where I am actually using it. So once I click the icon its value comes true but cant edit inside the already value that returns from the server.

```js
const [agent, setAgent] = useState<EstateAgentResponse | null>(null)
  const [enableField, setEnableField] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { id } = params

        const agentUsers = await getEstaAgentUsers(parseInt(id!, 10))
        const agent = await getEstateAgentById(parseInt(id!, 10))

        setAgentUsers(agentUsers)
        setAgent(agent)
      } catch (error) {
        // ToDo:
        // We should handle the error message
        toast.error(`${error}`)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

 const handleInputField = () => {
    setEnableField(!enableField)
  }

<PencilAltIcon className="block h-4 w-4" aria-hidden="true" onClick={handleInputField} />
                              <InputField
                                name="businessName"
                                label="Business name"
                                disabled={!enableField}
                                value={agent?.businessName}
                                type="text"
                                rules={{
                                  required: 'This is required',
                                }}
                              />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to made the state instead of direct passing the value `agent?.businessName` in `InputField` as you can see the below code, I hope this would be helpful and also works. thanks

```
const [agent, setAgent] = useState<EstateAgentResponse | null>(null)
  const [enableField, setEnableField] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [businessName, setBusinessName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { id } = params

        const agentUsers = await getEstaAgentUsers(parseInt(id!, 10))
        const agent = await getEstateAgentById(parseInt(id!, 10));
        setBusinessName(agent?.businessName);

        setAgentUsers(agentUsers)
        setAgent(agent)
      } catch (error) {
        // ToDo:
        // We should handle the error message
        toast.error(`${error}`)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

 const handleInputField = () => {
    setEnableField(!enableField)
  }

<PencilAltIcon className="block h-4 w-4" aria-hidden="true" onClick={handleInputField} />
                              <InputField
                                name="businessName"
                                label="Business name"
                                disabled={!enableField}
                                value={businessName}
                                onChange={e => setBusinessName(e.target.name)}
                                type="text"
                                rules={{
                                  required: 'This is required',
                                }}
                              />
```

In `input` component you need to add `onChange` prop as you can see the below code

```
<input
          {...field}
          //   required={props.required}
          disabled={props.disabled}
          value={props.value}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          type={props.type}
          autoComplete={props.autoComplete}
          pattern={props.pattern}
          className={`mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm  rounded-md ${
            error ? 'border-red-500' : 'border-gray-500'
          }
          ${
            props.disabled
              ? 'disabled:shadow-none disabled:bg-slate-50 disabled:text-slate-500 disabled:border-slate-200'
              : 'border-gray-500'
          } `}
        />
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thank you for that, like your thoughts..still though I cant edit... :(

Comment: Hey Ahmad is working now. Thank you super much

Comment: No worries, I will be happy to help you again :)